# Correct way to show iAd Banner View at the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to show iAd Banner View at the bottom of the screen. Also I want to hide it before the first `bannerViewDidLoadAd` and after `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError` methods calls and restore it after any further `bannerViewDidLoadAd` method calls. What is the correct way to achieve such behavior?

This is what I've tried:

- Add iAd Banner View to the view controller via interface builder in XCode and choose view contoller as the delegate of this view
- Add the following functions to the view contoller's implementation -- https://gist.github.com/ellneal/1082499
- Add the calls to this methods to the `bannerViewDidLoadAd` and `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError`:

  ```
  - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
  {
      [self showBannerView:banner animated:YES];
  }

  - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
  {
      [self hideBannerView:banner animated:YES];
  }
  ```

In this case I see a blank screen instead of ad before bannerViewDidLoadAd method was called and the iAd Banner View doesn't appear again when the connection established again (I think that it's because of `removeFromSuperview` method call). How can I fix it? Maybe there is a more correct way to achieve such behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you should consider using `setCanDisplayAds:` on your view controller. See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iAd/Reference/UIViewController_iAd_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Import iAd and set the property on your root view controller, or on the content view controller you wish to display ads at the bottom of.